# Coordinate Not Match - Convert Shapefile to Geojson

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, convert, geojson

I'm a newbie at GIS programming and I have a problem with file conversion. I've tried to convert shp file to geojson, and the coordinates do not match. But when I try to convert it to kml, it goes well.

geojson output file result :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "KODEBPS": "3324010001", "KODE": "3324010001", "COUNT": 1, "DESA": "Blumah", "KECAMATAN": "Plantungan", "KABUPATEN": "Kendal", "PROPINSI": "Jawa Tengah", "KODEBPS_1": "3324010001", "KECAMATAN_1": "Plantungan", "KODE_KAB": "3324", "KABUPATEN_1": "Kendal", "KODE_PROP": 33.000000, "PROPINSI_1": "Jawa Tengah" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 383707.21875, 9211513.0 ], [ 383803.8125, 9211530.0 ], [ 383873.21875, 9211524.0 ], [ 383915.28125, 9211515.0 ], [ 383958.46875, 9211498.0 ], [ 383994.625, 9211437.0 ], [ 384024.78125, 9211391.0 ], [ 384035.125, 9211321.0 ], [ 384034.5625, 9211260.0 ], [ 384034.4375, 9211214.0 ], [ 384023.875, 9211146.0 ], [ 384013.5, 9211086.0 ], [ 384011.5625, 9211044.0 ], [ 384025.53125, 9210967.0 ], [ 384039.0625, 9210918.0 ], [ 384041.53125, 9210876.0 ], [ 384056.59375, 9210833.0 ], [ 384079.15625, 9210783.0 ], [ 384120.15625, 9210724.0 ], [ 384158.03125, 9210681.0 ], [ 384197.96875, 9210637.0 ], [ 384236.90625, 9210601.0 ], [ 384265.28125, 9210577.0 ], [ 384313.65625, 9210547.0 ], [ 384266.09375, 9210513.0 ], [ 384240.78125, 9210481.0 ], [ 384235.34375, 9210442.0 ], [ 384230.8125, 9210406.0 ], [ 384191.40625, 9210394.0 ], [ 384154.5, 9210371.0 ], [ 384110.375, 9210327.0 ], [ 384079.375, 9210290.0 ], [ 384069.53125, 9210244.0 ], [ 384039.65625, 9210212.0 ], [ 384011.75, 9210142.0 ], [ 383986.90625, 9210088.0 ], [ 383951.4375, 9210057.0 ], [ 383912.5625, 9210018.0 ], [ 383876.34375, 9209942.0 ], [ 383839.875, 9209902.0 ], [ 383799.625, 9209876.0 ], [ 383773.71875, 9209835.0 ], [ 383762.46875, 9209778.0 ], [ 383730.53125, 9209742.0 ], [ 383728.15625, 9209698.0 ], [ 383740.65625, 9209665.0 ], [ 383701.6875, 9209589.0 ], [ 383663.0, 9209559.0 ], [ 383620.5, 9209507.0 ], [ 383597.09375, 9209474.0 ], [ 383561.1875, 9209413.0 ], [ 383544.375, 9209380.0 ], [ 383521.625, 9209331.0 ], [ 383514.71875, 9209296.0 ], [ 383506.25, 9209235.0 ], [ 383508.4375, 9209195.0 ], [ 383517.875, 9209142.0 ], [ 383518.375, 9209083.0 ], [ 383511.4375, 9209038.0 ], [ 383506.53125, 9209002.0 ], [ 383491.25, 9208962.0 ], [ 383477.3125, 9208917.0 ], [ 383459.875, 9208876.0 ], [ 383433.125, 9208820.0 ], [ 383409.875, 9208768.0 ], [ 383385.46875, 9208731.0 ], [ 383362.21875, 9208680.0 ], [ 383338.96875, 9208608.0 ], [ 383318.03125, 9208551.0 ], [ 383304.09375, 9208494.0 ], [ 383291.3125, 9208436.0 ], [ 383270.375, 9208362.0 ], [ 383252.9375, 9208317.0 ], [ 383237.84375, 9208264.0 ], [ 383227.375, 9208209.0 ], [ 383214.59375, 9208154.0 ], [ 383205.28125, 9208105.0 ], [ 383199.46875, 9208067.0 ], [ 383189.0625, 9208019.0 ], [ 383177.96875, 9207948.0 ], [ 383172.375, 9207913.0 ], [ 383125.75, 9207878.0 ], [ 383096.09375, 9207798.0 ], [ 383085.6875, 9207749.0 ], [ 383069.875, 9207715.0 ], [ 383024.5, 9207682.0 ], [ 382986.75, 9207654.0 ], [ 382967.625, 9207621.0 ], [ 382952.84375, 9207581.0 ], [ 382938.90625, 9207490.0 ], [ 382929.53125, 9207439.0 ], [ 382917.5625, 9207380.0 ], [ 382910.03125, 9207312.0 ], [ 382887.9375, 9207252.0 ], [ 382854.21875, 9207184.0 ], [ 382826.34375, 9207132.0 ], [ 382804.25, 9207089.0 ], [ 382779.84375, 9207037.0 ], [ 382760.0625, 9206986.0 ], [ 382738.0, 9206918.0 ], [ 382706.59375, 9206831.0 ], [ 382671.71875, 9206732.0 ], [ 382634.53125, 9206652.0 ], [ 382601.96875, 9206579.0 ], [ 382561.3125, 9206478.0 ], [ 382525.25, 9206414.0 ], [ 382506.65625, 9206375.0 ], [ 382479.6875, 9206349.0 ], [ 382460.1875, 9206257.0 ], [ 382444.0, 9206214.0 ], [ 382428.84375, 9206182.0 ], [ 382408.03125, 9206146.0 ], [ 382384.6875, 9206099.0 ], [ 382369.59375, 9206064.0 ], [ 382347.0625, 9206027.0 ], [ 382317.1875, 9205999.0 ], [ 382274.65625, 9205979.0 ], [ 382240.21875, 9205962.0 ], [ 382196.75, 9205926.0 ], [ 382194.75, 9205877.0 ], [ 382202.875, 9205839.0 ], [ 382196.25, 9205790.0 ], [ 382171.625, 9205752.0 ], [ 382145.90625, 9205726.0 ], [ 382075.625, 9205678.0 ], [ 382051.65625, 9205643.0 ], [ 382051.46875, 9205607.0 ], [ 382045.4375, 9205561.0 ], [ 382006.9375, 9205486.0 ], [ 381983.53125, 9205453.0 ], [ 381965.65625, 9205420.0 ], [ 381938.375, 9205359.0 ], [ 381880.875, 9205371.0 ], [ 381845.0, 9205358.0 ], [ 381794.71875, 9205355.0 ], [ 381754.75, 9205339.0 ], [ 381722.34375, 9205317.0 ], [ 381695.125, 9205294.0 ], [ 381651.5625, 9205261.0 ], [ 381615.65625, 9205234.0 ], [ 381576.59375, 9205195.0 ], [ 381549.875, 9205167.0 ], [ 381518.90625, 9205138.0 ], [ 381482.3125, 9205108.0 ], [ 381444.71875, 9205106.0 ], [ 381407.40625, 9205135.0 ], [ 381372.53125, 9205164.0 ], [ 381329.21875, 9205206.0 ], [ 381289.53125, 9205252.0 ], [ 381248.625, 9205297.0 ], [ 381216.15625, 9205328.0 ], [ 381176.4375, 9205356.0 ], [ 381139.15625, 9205386.0 ], [ 381105.46875, 9205416.0 ], [ 381049.46875, 9205462.0 ], [ 381072.75, 9205530.0 ], [ 381131.40625, 9205525.0 ], [ 381190.65625, 9205550.0 ], [ 381255.15625, 9205586.0 ], [ 381273.15625, 9205620.0 ], [ 381299.09375, 9205659.0 ], [ 381323.78125, 9205698.0 ], [ 381345.28125, 9205732.0 ], [ 381387.5625, 9205778.0 ], [ 381428.5, 9205810.0 ], [ 381467.125, 9205841.0 ], [ 381507.90625, 9205876.0 ], [ 381528.25, 9205907.0 ], [ 381564.4375, 9205944.0 ], [ 381603.6875, 9205965.0 ], [ 381641.5, 9205998.0 ], [ 381673.71875, 9206020.0 ], [ 381695.53125, 9206054.0 ], [ 381730.65625, 9206085.0 ], [ 381760.71875, 9206112.0 ], [ 381801.40625, 9206161.0 ], [ 381832.8125, 9206182.0 ], [ 381866.09375, 9206202.0 ], [ 381883.78125, 9206246.0 ], [ 381895.9375, 9206285.0 ], [ 381903.09375, 9206325.0 ], [ 381908.78125, 9206365.0 ], [ 381910.3125, 9206439.0 ], [ 381898.75, 9206479.0 ], [ 381892.21875, 9206524.0 ], [ 381887.875, 9206579.0 ], [ 381886.84375, 9206616.0 ], [ 381900.46875, 9206659.0 ], [ 381914.6875, 9206705.0 ], [ 381934.3125, 9206742.0 ], [ 381961.34375, 9206774.0 ], [ 381992.6875, 9206807.0 ], [ 382008.625, 9206845.0 ], [ 382018.84375, 9206887.0 ], [ 382028.625, 9206931.0 ], [ 382039.5625, 9206986.0 ], [ 382059.8125, 9207044.0 ], [ 382075.8125, 9207095.0 ], [ 382089.90625, 9207136.0 ], [ 382117.6875, 9207183.0 ], [ 382164.34375, 9207187.0 ], [ 382195.4375, 9207208.0 ], [ 382213.25, 9207271.0 ], [ 382226.25, 9207311.0 ], [ 382237.875, 9207349.0 ], [ 382254.625, 9207415.0 ], [ 382289.125, 9207490.0 ], [ 382307.71875, 9207528.0 ], [ 382330.5, 9207564.0 ], [ 382372.375, 9207620.0 ], [ 382391.9375, 9207659.0 ], [ 382410.4375, 9207691.0 ], [ 382447.15625, 9207749.0 ], [ 382480.4375, 9207811.0 ], [ 382508.53125, 9207868.0 ], [ 382526.6875, 9207918.0 ], [ 382545.15625, 9207992.0 ], [ 382552.78125, 9208035.0 ], [ 382577.3125, 9208106.0 ], [ 382612.71875, 9208176.0 ], [ 382675.9375, 9208230.0 ], [ 382726.375, 9208232.0 ], [ 382781.34375, 9208295.0 ], [ 382795.875, 9208360.0 ], [ 382801.0625, 9208428.0 ], [ 382835.03125, 9208481.0 ], [ 382869.3125, 9208583.0 ], [ 382895.875, 9208628.0 ], [ 382936.09375, 9208699.0 ], [ 382932.59375, 9208773.0 ], [ 382931.40625, 9208883.0 ], [ 382937.125, 9208953.0 ], [ 382936.09375, 9208993.0 ], [ 382926.15625, 9209030.0 ], [ 382909.25, 9209104.0 ], [ 382902.4375, 9209146.0 ], [ 382886.375, 9209187.0 ], [ 382863.59375, 9209238.0 ], [ 382838.96875, 9209340.0 ], [ 382830.34375, 9209377.0 ], [ 382849.5625, 9209460.0 ], [ 382879.34375, 9209524.0 ], [ 382878.09375, 9209578.0 ], [ 382863.53125, 9209624.0 ], [ 382847.5625, 9209675.0 ], [ 382831.84375, 9209746.0 ], [ 382839.5, 9209812.0 ], [ 382866.4375, 9209843.0 ], [ 382888.3125, 9209889.0 ], [ 382902.8125, 9209923.0 ], [ 382944.625, 9210040.0 ], [ 382938.65625, 9210079.0 ], [ 382933.96875, 9210124.0 ], [ 382950.8125, 9210177.0 ], [ 382958.3125, 9210216.0 ], [ 382930.5625, 9210271.0 ], [ 382926.1875, 9210387.0 ], [ 382938.0, 9210449.0 ], [ 382985.28125, 9210495.0 ], [ 383019.46875, 9210576.0 ], [ 383073.8125, 9210611.0 ], [ 383112.25, 9210658.0 ], [ 383154.34375, 9210690.0 ], [ 383215.875, 9210706.0 ], [ 383285.6875, 9210790.0 ], [ 383343.46875, 9210853.0 ], [ 383357.8125, 9210904.0 ], [ 383380.6875, 9210959.0 ], [ 383378.625, 9210999.0 ], [ 383379.75, 9211062.0 ], [ 383436.8125, 9211095.0 ], [ 383449.6875, 9211136.0 ], [ 383471.78125, 9211187.0 ], [ 383500.3125, 9211220.0 ], [ 383533.0, 9211279.0 ], [ 383637.4375, 9211296.0 ], [ 383677.75, 9211329.0 ], [ 383705.78125, 9211362.0 ], [ 383731.3125, 9211392.0 ], [ 383753.6875, 9211424.0 ], [ 383738.75, 9211469.0 ], [ 383707.21875, 9211513.0 ] ] ] } } ] }
```

and this is the kml output result :

```
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill>
</PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#a">
    <SimpleData name="KODEBPS">3324010001</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KODE">3324010001</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="COUNT">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="DESA">Blumah</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KECAMATAN">Plantungan</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KABUPATEN">Kendal</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="PROPINSI">Jawa Tengah</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KODEBPS_1">3324010001</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KECAMATAN_1">Plantungan</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KODE_KAB">3324</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KABUPATEN_1">Kendal</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="KODE_PROP">33</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="PROPINSI_1">Jawa Tengah</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-52.78125,9211513.0 43.8125,9211530.0 113.21875,9211524.0 155.28125,9211515.0 -161.53125,9211498.0 -125.375,9211437.0 -95.21875,9211391.0 -84.875,9211321.0 -85.4375,9211260.0 -85.5625,9211214.0 -96.125,9211146.0 -106.5,9211086.0 -108.4375,9211044.0 -94.46875,9210967.0 -80.9375,9210918.0 -78.46875,9210876.0 -63.40625,9210833.0 -40.84375,9210783.0 0.15625,9210724.0 38.03125,9210681.0 77.96875,9210637.0 116.90625,9210601.0 145.28125,9210577.0 -166.34375,9210547.0 146.09375,9210513.0 120.78125,9210481.0 115.34375,9210442.0 110.8125,9210406.0 71.40625,9210394.0 34.5,9210371.0 -9.625,9210327.0 -40.625,9210290.0 -50.46875,9210244.0 -80.34375,9210212.0 -108.25,9210142.0 -133.09375,9210088.0 -168.5625,9210057.0 152.5625,9210018.0 116.34375,9209942.0 79.875,9209902.0 39.625,9209876.0 13.71875,9209835.0 2.46875,9209778.0 -29.46875,9209742.0 -31.84375,9209698.0 -19.34375,9209665.0 -58.3125,9209589.0 -97,9209559 -139.5,9209507.0 -162.90625,9209474.0 161.1875,9209413.0 144.375,9209380.0 121.625,9209331.0 114.71875,9209296.0 106.25,9209235.0 108.4375,9209195.0 117.875,9209142.0 118.375,9209083.0 111.4375,9209038.0 106.53125,9209002.0 91.25,9208962.0 77.3125,9208917.0 59.875,9208876.0 33.125,9208820.0 9.875,9208768.0 -14.53125,9208731.0 -37.78125,9208680.0 -61.03125,9208608.0 -81.96875,9208551.0 -95.90625,9208494.0 -108.6875,9208436.0 -129.625,9208362.0 -147.0625,9208317.0 -162.15625,9208264.0 -172.625,9208209.0 174.59375,9208154.0 165.28125,9208105.0 159.46875,9208067.0 149.0625,9208019.0 137.96875,9207948.0 132.375,9207913.0 85.75,9207878.0 56.09375,9207798.0 45.6875,9207749.0 29.875,9207715.0 -15.5,9207682.0 -53.25,9207654.0 -72.375,9207621.0 -87.15625,9207581.0 -101.09375,9207490.0 -110.46875,9207439.0 -122.4375,9207380.0 -129.96875,9207312.0 -152.0625,9207252.0 174.21875,9207184.0 146.34375,9207132.0 124.25,9207089.0 99.84375,9207037.0 80.0625,9206986.0 58,9206918 26.59375,9206831.0 -8.28125,9206732.0 -45.46875,9206652.0 -78.03125,9206579.0 -118.6875,9206478.0 -154.75,9206414.0 -173.34375,9206375.0 159.6875,9206349.0 140.1875,9206257.0 124,9206214 108.84375,9206182.0 88.03125,9206146.0 64.6875,9206099.0 49.59375,9206064.0 27.0625,9206027.0 -2.8125,9205999.0 -45.34375,9205979.0 -79.78125,9205962.0 -123.25,9205926.0 -125.25,9205877.0 -117.125,9205839.0 -123.75,9205790.0 -148.375,9205752.0 -174.09375,9205726.0 115.625,9205678.0 91.65625,9205643.0 91.46875,9205607.0 85.4375,9205561.0 46.9375,9205486.0 23.53125,9205453.0 5.65625,9205420.0 -21.625,9205359.0 -79.125,9205371.0 -115,9205358 -165.28125,9205355.0 154.75,9205339.0 122.34375,9205317.0 95.125,9205294.0 51.5625,9205261.0 15.65625,9205234.0 -23.40625,9205195.0 -50.125,9205167.0 -81.09375,9205138.0 -117.6875,9205108.0 -155.28125,9205106.0 167.40625,9205135.0 132.53125,9205164.0 89.21875,9205206.0 49.53125,9205252.0 8.625,9205297.0 -23.84375,9205328.0 -63.5625,9205356.0 -100.84375,9205386.0 -134.53125,9205416.0 169.46875,9205462.0 -167.25,9205530.0 -108.59375,9205525.0 -49.34375,9205550.0 15.15625,9205586.0 33.15625,9205620.0 59.09375,9205659.0 83.78125,9205698.0 105.28125,9205732.0 147.5625,9205778.0 -171.5,9205810.0 -132.875,9205841.0 -92.09375,9205876.0 -71.75,9205907.0 -35.5625,9205944.0 3.6875,9205965.0 41.5,9205998.0 73.71875,9206020.0 95.53125,9206054.0 130.65625,9206085.0 160.71875,9206112.0 -158.59375,9206161.0 -127.1875,9206182.0 -93.90625,9206202.0 -76.21875,9206246.0 -64.0625,9206285.0 -56.90625,9206325.0 -51.21875,9206365.0 -49.6875,9206439.0 -61.25,9206479.0 -67.78125,9206524.0 -72.125,9206579.0 -73.15625,9206616.0 -59.53125,9206659.0 -45.3125,9206705.0 -25.6875,9206742.0 1.34375,9206774.0 32.6875,9206807.0 48.625,9206845.0 58.84375,9206887.0 68.625,9206931.0 79.5625,9206986.0 99.8125,9207044.0 115.8125,9207095.0 129.90625,9207136.0 157.6875,9207183.0 -155.65625,9207187.0 -124.5625,9207208.0 -106.75,9207271.0 -93.75,9207311.0 -82.125,9207349.0 -65.375,9207415.0 -30.875,9207490.0 -12.28125,9207528.0 10.5,9207564.0 52.375,9207620.0 71.9375,9207659.0 90.4375,9207691.0 127.15625,9207749.0 160.4375,9207811.0 -171.46875,9207868.0 -153.3125,9207918.0 -134.84375,9207992.0 -127.21875,9208035.0 -102.6875,9208106.0 -67.28125,9208176.0 -4.0625,9208230.0 46.375,9208232.0 101.34375,9208295.0 115.875,9208360.0 121.0625,9208428.0 155.03125,9208481.0 -170.6875,9208583.0 -144.125,9208628.0 -103.90625,9208699.0 -107.40625,9208773.0 -108.59375,9208883.0 -102.875,9208953.0 -103.90625,9208993.0 -113.84375,9209030.0 -130.75,9209104.0 -137.5625,9209146.0 -153.625,9209187.0 -176.40625,9209238.0 158.96875,9209340.0 150.34375,9209377.0 169.5625,9209460.0 -160.65625,9209524.0 -161.90625,9209578.0 -176.46875,9209624.0 167.5625,9209675.0 151.84375,9209746.0 159.5,9209812.0 -173.5625,9209843.0 -151.6875,9209889.0 -137.1875,9209923.0 -95.375,9210040.0 -101.34375,9210079.0 -106.03125,9210124.0 -89.1875,9210177.0 -81.6875,9210216.0 -109.4375,9210271.0 -113.8125,9210387.0 -102,9210449 -54.71875,9210495.0 -20.53125,9210576.0 33.8125,9210611.0 72.25,9210658.0 114.34375,9210690.0 175.875,9210706.0 -114.3125,9210790.0 -56.53125,9210853.0 -42.1875,9210904.0 -19.3125,9210959.0 -21.375,9210999.0 -20.25,9211062.0 36.8125,9211095.0 49.6875,9211136.0 71.78125,9211187.0 100.3125,9211220.0 133,9211279 -122.5625,9211296.0 -82.25,9211329.0 -54.21875,9211362.0 -28.6875,9211392.0 -6.3125,9211424.0 -21.25,9211469.0 -52.78125,9211513.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

the coordinate is much different. 
*I'm using qgis

Answer (score 3):

To find out the right CRS, create a new project in QGIS with **project** CRS set to EPSG:3857, load Google or OpenStreetMap background from the Openlayers plugin, and look where your data is placed.

If you set the **Layer** CRS of your data to `EPSG:32749 WGS 84 / UTM zone 49S`,  your data will be placed in the right position (at least the same place a Google search for the names takes you):

[image]

With that source CRS, you can convert the data to kml. You have to select `WGS84` as output CRS for kml.

Answer (score 2):

Those input points are not in `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84`, since that is (roughly) WGS84 lon / lat, and (taking the first point): `[ 383707.21875, 9211513.0 ]` is not a reasonable lon / lat combination.

What QGIS is (probably) doing in converting that point to `-52.78125,9211513.0` is taking 383707 and wrapping it around a few  times (383707.2185 - 1066 * 360 = -52.78125). The second coordinate is still not reasonable.

Shapefiles don't have mandatory coordinate reference system. So you need to figure out what the real coordinate reference system is for your data, and put that into your JSON, or transform the shapefile first.